# MVC add product to a pop up modal Cart without redirecting to a blank page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

i am working on asp.net MVC project ,i have 2 models "product" and "cart" my "index" view has the "product" model, And "show cart" view has "cart" model.
the index has products and has a modal that represent the cart,So that this modal has a link for the cart view which has a table of the added product but in another view

```
<div class="modal-body ">
    @Html.Action("ShowCart")
</div>
```

what i need to do is when i click to the "add product" button it brings the product from the database and add it to the cart and refresh the cart only not refreshing the entire page and not directed to "/Product/addtocart/product-id"
 Here's the action method for adding to cart:

```
 public void addtocart(int id)
    {
        var Product = db.Product.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
        var Cart = new Cart();

        ProductCart pc = new ProductCart()
        {

            Product = Product,
            Cart = Cart

        };
        pc.Cart.added_at = DateTime.Now;

        pc.Cart.product_id = pc.Product.id;
        db.Cart.Add(pc.Cart);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

this will direct me to a blank page "/Product/addtocart/product-id" what should i do to the action to make the button add the products to the cart and refresh the cart only ?

Comment: Do you know how to write JavaScript to send an HTTP request to the server and process the response? Do you know how to make the server return an HTTP status code as part of that result?

Comment: no not sure about it,but i am working with asp.net mvc can't i do this with it ?

Comment: If you want to have your page update on the client side without refreshing the entire page, you must use JavaScript on the client to accomplish that. On the server side you can use whatever you want (including ASP.NET MVC) to process the requests coming from the client.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot i will give it a try.